# DoesNotExist: [Model] matching query does not exist at id (ObjectId)

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am trying to query a unique document using its ObjectId. However the error comes up:

> DoesNotExist: Route matching query does not exist

When, upon passing this to my view as request, it prints out the corresponding ObjectId in ObjectId typeform. Therefore there shouldn't be a problem with the line `route_test = Route.objects.get(id=_id)`.
I have the following code:

**views.py**

```
def update(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        _id = request.POST.get('_id',ObjectId())
        print(_id)
        route_id = request.POST.get('route_id','')
        geometry = request.POST.get('geometry', '')
        properties = request.POST.get('properties','')

        #r = Route.objects.get(route_id='LTFRB_PUJ2616') --> I cannot use this
                                      #because it has 5 instances (Not Unique)
        #print (r["id"],r["properties"]) 

        test = Route.objects.get(id = ObjectId('587c4c3b203ada19e8e0ecf6'))
        print (test["id"], test["properties"])

        try:
            route_test = Route.objects.get(id=_id)
            print(route_test)
            Route.objects.get(id=_id).update(set__geometry=geometry, set__properties=properties)
            return HttpResponse("Success!")

        except:
            return HttpResponse("Error!")
```

**ajax**

```
 var finishBtn = L.easyButton({
     id:'finish',
     states: [{
              icon:"fa fa-check",
              onClick: function(btn){
                  selectedFeature.editing.disable();
                  layer.closePopup();
                  var editedFeature = selectedFeature.toGeoJSON();
                  alert("Updating:" + editedFeature.route_id);

                  $.ajax({
                     url: "/update/",
                     data: {id:editedFeature.id,
                            route_id: JSON.stringify(editedFeature.route_id),
                            geometry: JSON.stringify(editedFeature.geometry),
                            properties: JSON.stringify(editedFeature.properties)
                         }, 
                     type: 'POST'     
            });
 }
```

**model.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from mongoengine import *

class Route(Document):
    type = StringField(required=True)
    route_id = StringField(required=True)
    geometry = LineStringField()
    properties = DictField()

    meta = {'collection':'routes'}
```

What should be done? Even the line `test = Route.objects.get(id = ObjectId('587c4c3b203ada19e8e0ecf6'))` where I directly supplied the incoming `_id` has the same error...

Comment: I think you are not getting ID which you are sending through ajax. In `_id = request.POST.get('_id',ObjectId())`, you are getting `_id` and in ajax, you are passing `id`. So you are getting default value instead.

Comment: instead of object id, use string.. django handles converting the id to object id

Comment: @ManasviBatra I tried to make _id to `str(_id)` and passed it as `Routes.objects.get(id=ObjectiId(_id))` still empty..

Comment: Route.objects.get(id=str(_id)) and are you getting value for _id in your views??

Comment: @ManasviBatra that doesn't work too. It's being passed from my ajax view that comes directly from my mongodb document

Comment: @Reiion what I meant to say is that whether you are getting value for _id while you are printing it in your view? If yes, then try test = Route.objects.get(id = str(_id)) or just try test = Route.objects.get(id = '587c4c3b203ada19e8e0ecf6')